# Match dictionary value to its dictionary key and give the dictionary key as the output

Tags: python, dictionary, input

Hello I am new to learning python and i was wondering whether it was possible to obtain a dictonary key as an output from looking at its associated dictionary value?

I am currently practicing writing a simple rock, paper, scissor game and I am trying to complete a `HumanPlayer` subclass that allows an individual to choose their move. The string from the input call then goes through the `valid_input` function to ensure they are typing the correct words, but want i want the code to do is return (once it confirms the input is valid) the variable that provides the emoji icon (e.g. `rock = emoji.emojize(":rock:")`) which matches the dictionary key `rock`, instead of printing the dictionary value (`"rock"`) - (i think it is the dictionary value? Am i correct?) have attached [terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZ8PG.png) and code is below.

Would appreciate help please on this.

```
import emoji
import random

rock = emoji.emojize(":rock:")
paper = emoji.emojize(":scroll:")
scissors = emoji.emojize(":scissors:")
fire = emoji.emojize(":fire:")
water = emoji.emojize(":water_wave:")
dynamite = emoji.emojize(":firecracker:")

# dictionary
moves_dict = {
    rock: "rock",
    paper: "paper",
    scissors: "scissors",
    fire: "fire",
    water: "water",
    dynamite: "dynamite"
}

# moves_dict.keys() would return object not a list
# these objects are not subscriptable, we can't access them at a specific index.
# convert to a list
moves_keys = list(moves_dict.keys())
moves_values = list(moves_dict.values())

player_one_count = 0
player_two_count = 0


class Player:
    def move(self):
        pass

    def learn(self, my_move, their_move):
        pass


# Computer player - subclass of player
class RandomPlayer(Player):
    def move(self):
        return random.choice(moves_keys)


# Human player - subclass of player
class HumanPlayer(Player):
    def move(self):
        human_choice = valid_input(
            "Choose rock, paper, scissors, dynamite, fire or water\n", moves_values)
        return human_choice
```

Comment: Just reverse your dictionary.  Keys should be the input text, and values should be the emoji.

Comment: `moves_dict = {'rock': rock, ...}` etc.  Then `if human_choice in moves_dict:` wil check if the input is valid, and `moves_dict[human_choice]` will fetch the emoji.